# How to add ng2-table library to Angular seed?

Tags: angular

I have cloned [mgechev's angular-seed project](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) and now I want to add [ng2-table](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/).

## The error I get

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("
<pagination *ngIf="config.paging"
            class="pagination-sm"
            [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="page"
            [totalItems]="length"
            [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"
"): TableComponent@17:12
Can't bind to 'totalItems' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("
            class="pagination-sm"
            [(ngModel)]="page"
            [ERROR ->][totalItems]="length"
            [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"
            [maxSize]="maxSize"
"): TableComponent@18:12

// And continues...
```

However, I think the library is imported correctly, at least it appears as a source of the site:

[image: Chrome Source inspector]

## What I have done to import the library

**1.Create the html template (`table.component.html`)**

I just copied the example code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input *ngIf="config.filtering" placeholder="Filter all columns"
           [ngTableFiltering]="config.filtering"
           class="form-control"
           (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)"/>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<ng-table [config]="config"
          (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)"
          (cellClicked)="onCellClick($event)"
          [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
</ng-table>
<pagination *ngIf="config.paging"
            class="pagination-sm"
            [(ngModel)]="page"
            [totalItems]="length"
            [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"
            [maxSize]="maxSize"
            [boundaryLinks]="true"
            [rotate]="false"
            (pageChanged)="onChangeTable(config, $event)"
            (numPages)="numPages = $event">
</pagination>
<pre *ngIf="config.paging" class="card card-block card-header">
  Page: {{page}} / {{numPages}}
</pre>
```

**2.Create the `table.component.ts`**

Again, I copied the example code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TableData } from './table.data';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'table-demo',
  templateUrl: 'table.component.html'
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  // Just a copy and paste from the example
}
```

**3.Create the `table.data.ts` file that contains the data of the table**

Just copied.

**4.Create the `table.module.ts`**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TableComponent } from './table.component';

import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';

console.log(Ng2TableModule); // prints empty function: 'function Ng2TableModule() {}'

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, Ng2TableModule],
    declarations: [TableComponent],
    exports: [TableComponent]
})

export class TableModule { }
```

**5.Add the `TableModule` to the `app.module.ts`**

```
// ..
import { TableModule } from './table/table.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    TableModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

**6.Add the dependency to `SystemJS`**

I added the following lines in the file `project.config.ts` as suggested in the [wiki](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Add-external-dependency#full-example):

```
// ...

export class ProjectConfig extends SeedConfig {

  // ...

  constructor() {

    // ...

    this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths['ng2-table'] =
    `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/ng2-table/ng2-table`;

    this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['ng2-table'] = {
      main: 'ng2-table.js',
      defaultExtension : 'js'
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea of what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but I think you need ng2-bootstrap in addition to ng2-table.  ng2-bootstrap has the pagination component that you are referencing in the above code.